# The `pkg-config` command doesn't find the `bcm_host` package. How can I add the `.pc` files from `/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig` to pkg-config?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, software-installation

I am running a raspberry pi 3B (V 1.2). I am using the proprietary OpenGLES driver (Broadcom). I have just run a full `apt upgrade`.

I am trying to build SDL2 and I noticed that while it was being configured that the `brcm_host` packages weren't being found. I looked around and found that the appropriate `.pc` files are found in `/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig`, but when I run `pkg-config --list-all` the packages aren't found. I have looked around to see what might be going on and have seen some answers regarding setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, which doesn't seem to be set on my system. Is there a way to reset the paths that `pkg-config` looks in for `.pc` files?

To try and fix this I have tried to reinstall the raspberrypi-dev packages (`sudo apt install --reinstall libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi0`) and the package-config package (`sudo apt install pkg-config --reinstall pkg-config`, but this hasn't fixed the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: See the environment variables section in https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this! I see that I can set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to add custom paths, but I was assuming that there would be a system-wide solution integrated with the `deb` packages that provide the `.pc` files.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment by @tttapa, the best solution to my problem here is to add the directory containing the package config files using the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. I added this to my `.profile` file and it has worked well for me.

I think that this is the best solution, because I see now that adding them by default could mess up switching between the different OpenGL implementations.